# Debian 8 - SSL Certificate is not working

Tags: apache, ssl, https, debian

I have recently moved a website from my old web server with 123-reg.co.uk to a new Linode web server hosted with Linode.

I am running Apache with Debian 8.9.

123-reg provided me with an SSL certificate for my website which, of course, was deactivated when I moved the website to the new server. So I set to work manually reactivating the certificate on my new server.

I was able to get the necessary SSL files (CA Bundle, Key and Certificate) from 123-reg and I followed Linode's instructions to setup the SSL certificate on their servers using the following tutorials:

[First tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/obtain-a-commercially-signed-ssl-certificate-on-debian-and-ubuntu) and 
[second tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/ssl-apache2-debian-ubuntu).

Here is the site's config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # All of the files here exist on the server
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/zetec-it.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/zetec-it.com.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

  ServerAdmin webmaster@zetec-it.com
  ServerName  zetec-it.com
  ServerAlias www.zetec-it.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zetec-it.com/public_html
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/zetec-it.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/zetec-it.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The setup seems legit, but when I attempt to access the website via `https` the browser states that the connection isn't secure.

I'm fairly new to server admin; does anyone have any suggestions or potential solutions?

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>` You are binding your SSL connection to port 80. You should use Port 443.

Comment: @JonasSchwabe You are my hero of the god, I could kiss you!

Comment: @JonasSchwabe oddly enough, doing this has caused my site to redirect to another site hosted on my server, do you any idea why?

Comment: @JonasSchwabe Do I need to to include both ports, i.e. `<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>`?

Comment: You need two multiple hosts, one for HTTP and one for HTTPS. When switching this vhost to port 443 there has not been any virtualhost for an http connection to this domain. A default vhost might have been active which did the redirect.
You could either have an http vhost redirecting to https or just copy the vhost and have the same settings for 80 and 443.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Unfortunately, I'm not entirely sure how to have two vhosts for the same domain. If you have any insight on this point, feel free to provide it as an answer to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `VirtualHost` which is listening on port 443 in order to have working HTTPS. You configured your `VirtualHost` to listen on Port 80 while having `SSLEngine On`.

In order to get https working you would only need to change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>`.
Once you did that, you would not have a configuration that handles http connections to (there would not be any `VirtualHost` waiting for connections for `ServerName  zetec-it.com`).

There are generally to ways to go to serve http connections requesting the same hostname:

1. You redirect them to https using something like this (uses `mod_rewrite` in order to redirect to the same path):

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName zetec-it.com
     ServerAlias www.zetec-it.com

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule ^ https://zetec-it.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. You deliver the same content through http as well

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     # All of the files here exist on the server
     ServerAdmin webmaster@zetec-it.com
     ServerName  zetec-it.com
     ServerAlias www.zetec-it.com

     DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zetec-it.com/public_html
     LogLevel warn
     ErrorLog  /var/www/html/zetec-it.com/log/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/html/zetec-it.com/log/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Either way you need two config files, the https one (which is basically your example from above, remember to replace 80 with 443) and one for http which I gave you 2 examples for.
You can put them into separate files, remember to activate them in this case.